# Issues in getting streaming from ip camera

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer, ip-camera

I am using DIgoo (DG-MIQ) ip camera. I want to use it in windows form c#. But it is not connecting on the basis of ip of camera and i dont know what is the port of my digoo camera. following given is my code

```
 public partial class vstream : Form
 {
     MJPEGStream stream;
     public vstream()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         stream = new MJPEGStream(" http://192.100.0.106");
         stream.NewFrame += stream_NewFrame;
     }

     private void stream_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
     {
         Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
         pictureBox1.Image = bmp;    
     }

     private void btnstrt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         stream.Start();
     }

     private void btnstp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         stream.Stop();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can see your camera output in web browser, right click on image(video) and choose open image in new tab to see full address of your video stream. 
Another option is using VLC player to finding out what is your camera streaming path.